How to use JointStiffnessController on a MultibodyPlant with more than one body
I have been using the PidController for my 7dof robot in Drake, and now I want to try out the JointStiffnessController. However, the JointStiffnessController takes in a MultibodyPlant, and it throws an exception if the dimensionality of the plant is different than the dimensionality of the controlled variable. However, my plant has other models besides my robot (e.g. it has a gripper as well, and some cereal boxes). So I have a conceptual question and then a practical question.

Conceptually I'm having trouble understanding why the JointStiffnessController needs a plant. I thought that systems were supposed to communicate through the use of input and output ports. Shouldn't the plant expose some sort of gravity-force output port, per model? When I define my own system, is it okay to take a reference to a plant directly?

Practically, how do I update my code in order to use the JointStiffnessController? Should I just make another MultibodyPlant with only my robot and just wire it up to the same scene graph as my other plant?



Before we go too far here, note that there is now a better way to implement the JointStiffnessControl, using InverseDynamics to compute the gravity comp and implicit PD to handle large gains.  See https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/issues/309. There may still be limits to controlling a subset of the plant (which can probably be easily remedied), but this is the better path.

Thanks @RussTedrake. I'll just add my two cents about some conceptual findings as I've been playing more with Drake. It seems to be a common practice for controllers to have their own MultibodyPlant instances and their own plant contexts. All statefullness (joint positions, etc) are encapsulated inside the context objects and communicated by means of the input/output ports.
